# Kummer Theory: Understanding the isomorphism $F^\times \cap E^{\times n}/F^{\times n} \to \operatorname{Hom}(G,\mu_n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, group-cohomology, kummer-theory

Let $F$ be a field and let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity in $F$.

Now I am trying to understand the following  section from [Milne's *Fields and Galois Theory*](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf) (page 73):

[image]

The part *"Thus we obtain an isomorphism"* seems to imply that the map $F^\times \cap E^{\times n}/F^{\times n} \to \operatorname{Hom}(G,\mu_n)$ is somehow derived from the previous cohomology sequence. However, this is the part where I am stuck. In particular, I do not see where $\operatorname{Hom}(G,\mu_n)$ comes from.

My first thought is that it has something to do with $H^1(G,\mu_n)$ but classes of crossed homomorphism are not quite the same as homomorphisms.

Could you please explain this part for me? Thank you!

Comment: In the cohomology exact sequence, the image of the $n$-th power map is $F^{\times n}$, so you get an isomorphism $(F^\times\cap E^{\times n})/F^{\times n}\cong H^1(G, \mu_n)$. But here $\mu_n$ is contained in $F^\times$, hence $G$ acts trivially on $\mu_n$ and $H^1(G,\mu_n)= Hom (G,\mu_n) $.